# Multiple File Uploads from Node Client to Node Server

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

Hi I am running a node server with multer to upload multiple files.

```
const multer = require('multer');
const app = express();

const upload = multer({dest:'uploads/'});

const SERVER_PORT = 8080;

app.listen(SERVER_PORT,()=>{
    console.log("Server listening")
})

app.post('/upload/bak', upload.array('file'), (req,res)=>{
    console.log(JSON.stringify(req.files[0]))
    // console.log("Files uploaded: " + req.files.reduce((prev,current)=>{
    //     console.log(JSON.stringify(prev))
    // }))

    res.end(JSON.stringify({
        status:"complete"
    }));

})
```

Now I am able to post multiple files (stored on system) using `postman` using a `form-data` `post` request and selecting multiple files.

What I am trying to accomplish here is doing it with another Node Application (Preferably using `axios` and `streams` so that if the files are large they dont eating all the memory).

How do I put multiple streams in `formdata` and post it so that above application is able to handle it?

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You can upload using FORMDATA.

```
    const formData = new FormData();

    formData.append('avatar',file)

    return  await axios.post(this.UPLOAD_ENDPOINT, formData,{
        headers: {
            'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
        }
    });
```

Read more: https://www.techiediaries.com/react-formdata-file-upload-multipart-form-tutorial/

Comment: Thanks Harvey, however File I am trying to upload through node application. How do I get 'file' variable?